# I can't show a multipolygon on a map in OpenLayers

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, openlayers

I cannot assign polygon property to the area I want on the map in my project that I have created with open layers and angular

**My method that I have created my map and then call in ngOnit()**

```js
IntilazeMapParsel() {
  this.view = new View({
    center: [3876682.9740679907, 4746346.604388495],
    zoom: 6.5,
    // minZoom:5.8
  });
  console.log("mao")
  this.mapParsel = new Map({
    view:this.view,
    layers: [
      new Tile({
        source: new XYZ({
          url: 'http://mt0.google.com/vt/lyrs=y&hl=en&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}',
        }), 
        zIndex: -5444
      }),
    ],
    target: 'ol-map-parsel'
  }); 
}
```

**Here is the code I wrote because I want to show the multypolygon value on my map.**

**I don't understand why it doesn't appear on the map, I would appreciate it if you could help.**

Comment: You need to specify dataProjection and featureProjection as options in the readFeature call.  The data is EPSG:4326.  The feature needs to be in the view projection which is EPSGL3857

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/wkt-forked-1x4lw?file=/main.js

Comment: thank you bro i solved the problem thanks to you